# askopenfile() got multiple values for argument 'mode' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fileopendialog

I am writing a python program in python which require that I use open Dialog

but I am getting the following error

askopenfile() got multiple values for argument 'mode'

My code

```
def open_file():
    browse_text.set("loading...")
    file = askopenfile(root, mode='r', title="Choose a file", filetype=[("pdf file", "*.pdf")])
    if file:
        read_file = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        page = read_file.getPage(0)
        page_content = page.extractText()

        text_box = tk.Tex(root, height=10, width=50, padx=15, pady=15)
        text_box.insert(1.0, page_content)
        text_box.grid(column=1, row=3)

browse_text = tk.StringVar();
browse_btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=browse_text, command=lambda: open_file(), bg="blue", fg="white", font="arial", height=3, width=15)
browse_text.set("Open file")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`askopenfile` does not accept a `root` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile).

```
>>> from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
>>> help(askopenfile)
Help on function askopenfile in module tkinter.filedialog:

askopenfile(mode='r', **options)
    Ask for a filename to open, and returned the opened file
```

So just change

```
file = askopenfile(root, mode='r', title="Choose a file", filetype=[("pdf file", "*.pdf")])
```

to

```
file = askopenfile(mode='r', title="Choose a file", filetype=[("pdf file", "*.pdf")])
```